# How do I compare Times in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a filter on a list based on a given time interval (2 cells in my spreadsheet which will input a timestamp C4 and C5). I have scoured the internet for a while and found out that the Javascript code used in Google Apps Script is different from the usual Javascript, so I haven't found a usable code snippet for my case.
The code is something like this:

```
var beginningTimeValue = new Date('2020-01-01 ' + ss.getRange("C4").getValue());
var endingTimeValue = new Date('2020-01-01 ' + ss.getRange("C5").getValue());
if(!beginningTimeValue == ""){
    Logger.log(beginningDateValue);
    unique = unique.filter(function(row)
                              {
                                const bTime = Date.parse(row[4]);
                                Logger.log(bTime);
                                Logger.log(beginningTimeValue);
                                return bTime.getTime() >= beginningTimeValue.getTime();
                              }
                             );
  }
```

The value in row[4] is of DateTime value ("12/01/2021 00:03:35" for example). How do I filter this row out if I want the time to be between 08:00:00 and 13:00:00?

Comment: In your question, I think that it is important for understanding your question to know whether the values of `ss.getRange("C4").getValue()`, `ss.getRange("C5").getValue()` and `row[4]` are the date object or the string value. And, can you provide the sample values of them?

Comment: @Tanaike, I have given the data values already (08:00:00 and 13:00:00 respectively for the C4 and C5 values; 12/01/2021 00:03:35 for the row)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `I have given the data values already (08:00:00 and 13:00:00 respectively for the C4 and C5 values; 12/01/2021 00:03:35 for the row)` and your question, unfortunately, I couldn't understand whether those are the date object.

Comment: Do you still not understand what I am trying to do, @Tanaike?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that I understand your question. But, in your situation, I thought that the script is changed by the value type of `ss.getRange("C4").getValue()`, `ss.getRange("C5").getValue()` and `row[4]`. So, first, I asked about it. But I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for my poor English skill, again.

Comment: @Tanaike No problem. I've seen some code online that told me that I can only compare Date objects in Javascript, so that's why I constructed beginningTimeValue and endingTimeValue the way I did. If there is a way to compare the Times directly without transforming into Date, then I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Three points:

- **To filter by two conditions instead of one, simply combine the two conditions with an `&&` operator.**

So:

`return bTime.getTime() >= beginningTimeValue.getTime(); && bTime.getTime() <= endingTimeValue.getTime()`

instead of

`return bTime.getTime() >= beginningTimeValue.getTime();`

- **Do not use both [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) simultaneously, since they both do the same.**

`const bTime = Date.parse(row[4]);`

already returns you a timestamp in ms, if you try to apply

`bTime.getTime()`

on it - this will result in an error.

- **Be careful** with

`Logger.log(beginningDateValue);`

given that your variable is called `beginningTimeValue` and not `beginningDateValue`.

**Sample**

Provided that `beginningTimeValue`, `endingTimeValue` and `unique` look like the harcoded values below, the following code snippet will work correctly for you:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var beginningTimeValue = new Date('2020-01-01 08:00:00');
  var endingTimeValue = new Date('2020-01-01 13:00:00');
  var unique = [["value","value","value","value","12/01/2021 00:03:35","value"],["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 00:03:35","value"], ["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 08:03:35","value"], ["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 13:03:35","value"]]
  if(!beginningTimeValue == ""){
    Logger.log(beginningTimeValue);
    unique = unique.filter(function(row)
                           {
                             const bTime = Date.parse(row[4]);
                             Logger.log(bTime);
                             Logger.log(beginningTimeValue);
                             return bTime >= beginningTimeValue.getTime() && bTime <= endingTimeValue.getTime();
                           }
                          );
    console.log("unique: " + unique)
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

- If you want to compare the times only (not the dates), you need to hardcode the date of `row[4]` to the same value like in `beginningTimeValue` and `endingTimeValue`. For this you can use the methods [setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), [setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) and [setYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear).
- Also, if your code should only work base don either vlaues are provided by a user in the cells C4 and C5 - you should adapt your code accordingly.
- Be careful with your conditional statements: Even if `ss.getRange("C4").getValue()` is an empty string or an invalid input - `beginningTimeValue` will still not be an empty string, but rather the beginning of Unix time.

Sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
var beginningTimeValue = new Date('2020-01-01 ' + ss.getRange("C4").getValue());
console.log("beginningTimeValue: " + beginningTimeValue)
var endingTimeValue = new Date('2020-01-01 ' + ss.getRange("C5").getValue());
console.log("endingTimeValue: " + endingTimeValue)
  var unique = [["value","value","value","value","12/01/2021 00:03:35","value"],["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 00:03:35","value"], ["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 08:03:35","value"], ["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 13:03:35","value"]]
  if(!ss.getRange("C4").getValue() == ""){
    Logger.log("beginningTimeValue: " + beginningTimeValue);
    unique = unique.filter(function(row)
                           {
                             const bTime = new Date(row[4]);
                             bTime.setYear(2020);
                             // Be careful - months start in Javascript with 0!
                             bTime.setMonth(0);
                             bTime.setDate(1);
                             Logger.log(bTime);
                             if(ss.getRange("C5").getValue() != ""){
                               return bTime >= beginningTimeValue.getTime() && bTime <= endingTimeValue.getTime();
                             }
                             else{
                               return bTime >= beginningTimeValue.getTime();
                             }
                           }
                          );
    console.log("unique: " + unique)
  }
}
```

- Keep im mind that Stackoverflow is not there to provide you a complete solution, but rather to help you troubleshooting and provide you references and samples that will guide you in the right direction. This will allow to incorporate the necessary modification into your code. You still need to have some basic understanding about coding to apply the sample to your script correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't help me. If I put your code and comment out the following part: 
" && bTime <= endingTimeValue.getTime(); " then the results will be:
12/01/2021 00:03:35
01/01/2020 08:03:35
01/01/2020 13:03:35
The first entry is not supposed to go through to the final list

Comment: Then why do you comment out `&& bTime <= endingTimeValue.getTime();`? This is the criteria necessary for the first entry not to go through.

Comment: Because I need the program to work even if endingTimeValue isn't given as an input by the user. I have a separate branch with " if(!endingTimeValue == ""){...} " for that reason. Either way, I'm trying to filter by HOURS, not dates, since I have code that already does that.

Comment: Ok, that was not clear from your question. So how do you know that the endingTime is meant to be 13:00 o'clock - if the user does not provide the information? You can do an `if` statement, something like `if(!beginningTimeValue == ""){return bTime >= beginningTimeValue.getTime() && bTime <= endingTimeValue.getTime();
} else{return bTime >= beginningTimeValue.getTime()}  -if this is what you want.`

Comment: As for filtering by hours only - as you noticed yourself, you need to convert timestmaps into ms in order to be able to compare them. This means that you need to hardcode the day, month and year of `row[4]` to the same values like `beginningTimeValue` and `endingTimeValue` - before converting it to ms. I will update my answer with an example.